# Form data not getting set

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">           
        </script>

        <script>
            function getCords(){
                var x=document.forms["get_loc"]["loc"].value;
                var y=x.replace(" ","+");
                $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%22"+y+"%22&key=%22My_Google_API_Key%22&sensor=false&output=json",
                    function(data, textStatus){
                        //alert(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0]);
                        //document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML=data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0] 
                        $("#lon").val(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1]);
                        $("#lat").val(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0]);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            return true;            
            }
        </script>

    </head> 

    <body>
        <form name="get_loc" id="get_loc" action="get_loc.php" onsubmit="return getCords()" method="post">
        Location:   <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc"/></br>
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="0"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="lon" id="lon" value="0"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_button"/></br>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is get the co-ordinates of a location using this function and pass it to a separate PHP file for some database actions. But when I try to get the values printed in the PHP file, the latitude and longitude both still come up as 0.

What is going wrong here?

P:S : When returning false and checking alert, its giving me the correct Latitude. So its not the error of google API.

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.` try adding protocol `http: or https:`

Comment: @Jai No help. Actually I picked up that URL from a working script. So I dint even care to look at it. The alert function is giving me the correct latitude. Means everything is working, except the form value is not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with submitting a form in this fashion is this: You are calling a javascript function at the exact moment you are submitting the form. This does not cancel the actual form submit and the javascript-function (Async) does not have the time to set the fields. The page is already long gone before the async-request is finished.

Luckily, you can cancel the original event and after getting the results of the api, submit the form. Don't forget that this can take some time and the user is not aware of anything going on, let them know stuff is happening by showing some sort of "loader".

Also, separate the html from the javascript, by using the jQuery submit event. Here is how that would work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">           
    </script>

    <script>
        function getCords(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            var callingForm = $(this);                
            var location = callingForm.find("#loc").val();
                location = location.replace(" ","+");
            $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%22"+y+"%22&key=%22My_Google_API_Key%22&sensor=false&output=json",
                function(data, textStatus){
                    //alert(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0]);
                    //document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML=data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0] 
                    $("#lon").val(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1]);
                    $("#lat").val(data.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0]);
                console.log(data);
                callingForm.submit();
            });
        return false;            
        }
        $(".jsFormSubmit").submit(getCords);


    </script>

</head> 

<body>
    <form name="get_loc" id="get_loc" class="jsFormSubmit" action="get_loc.php" method="post">
    Location:   <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc"/></br>
    <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lon" id="lon" value="0"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_button"/></br>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Its still not getting submitted.

Comment: If you exchange the callingForm.submit(); for a callingForm[0].submit(); it should work.

Comment: Actually, I got a work around. As data was small, I redirected the link filling in the values and receiving on the other end using $_GET :)

Comment: I will try you suggestion also.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things pretty much doom what you're trying to do.  You can't ajax to google like that, cross domain security restrictions.  And "your google api key" isn't going to work.  The client browser would have to be just you, or a person with their own key who is willing to use it.

Comment: But, the alert is giving me the correct latitude. Means, the google API is working. The problem I think is in setting the hidden fields in the form.